# create circular arc menu item with css

Tags: css

How I can create circular arc menu item with css? like this photo

[image]

I have 6 item as image that I want show images in arc of circle, I want just show arc of circle not full circle.

I try many way but I can create good thing

I write this code but with any resize window and zoom out all position change

```
.img { position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); width: 43px; height: 36px; }

#img1 { left: 18px; top: 44vh; }

#img2 { left: 62px; top: 54vh; }

#img3 { left: 80px; top: 64vh; }

#img4 { left: 74px; top: 74vh; }

<div id="menu">
    <img class='img' src="...." id="img1">
    <img class='img' src="...." id="img2">
    <img class='img' src="...." id="img3">
    <img class='img' src="...." id="img4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps<3

```css
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-arc {
  --width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--width);
  height: calc(var(--width) * 2);
  border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 0% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: calc(100% / 6);
}

.circle-arc::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 0% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 55px solid transparent;
  border-left: hidden;
  /* border: double 1em transparent; */
  /* border-radius: 30px; */
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to right, transparent -10%, #0f0f0f 50%);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}

.arc_button:not(:first-child, :last-child) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.arc_button:first-child,
.arc_button:last-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.arc_button:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) * 1.28))) translateY(calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) * 1.155)));
}

.arc_button:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) * 1.066)));
}

.arc_button:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) * 1.28))) translateY(calc(var(--width) - (var(--width) * 0.866)));
}

.arc_button svg {
  transform: scale(1.7);
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Profile</title>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="circle-arc">
    <div class="arc_button">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
            <path d="M160-120v-480l320-240 320 240v480H560v-280H400v280H160Z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arc_button">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
            <path
              d="M784-120 532-372q-30 24-69 38t-83 14q-109 0-184.5-75.5T120-580q0-109 75.5-184.5T380-840q109 0 184.5 75.5T640-580q0 44-14 83t-38 69l252 252-56 56ZM380-400q75 0 127.5-52.5T560-580q0-75-52.5-127.5T380-760q-75 0-127.5 52.5T200-580q0 75 52.5 127.5T380-400Z"
            />
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arc_button">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
            <path
              d="M480-280v-400q-83 0-141.5 58.5T280-480q0 83 58.5 141.5T480-280Zm0 200q-83 0-156-31.5T197-197q-54-54-85.5-127T80-480q0-83 31.5-156T197-763q54-54 127-85.5T480-880q83 0 156 31.5T763-763q54 54 85.5 127T880-480q0 83-31.5 156T763-197q-54 54-127 85.5T480-80Z"
            />
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arc_button">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
            <path d="M160-120v-480l320-240 320 240v480H560v-280H400v280H160Z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arc_button">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
            <path
              d="m370-80-16-128q-13-5-24.5-12T307-235l-119 50L78-375l103-78q-1-7-1-13.5v-27q0-6.5 1-13.5L78-585l110-190 119 50q11-8 23-15t24-12l16-128h220l16 128q13 5 24.5 12t22.5 15l119-50 110 190-103 78q1 7 1 13.5v27q0 6.5-2 13.5l103 78-110 190-118-50q-11 8-23 15t-24 12L590-80H370Zm112-260q58 0 99-41t41-99q0-58-41-99t-99-41q-59 0-99.5 41T342-480q0 58 40.5 99t99.5 41Z"
            />
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```